# Play Haven SDK import

Tags: android, playhaven

I am importing Play Haven sdk in a test project, its importing successfully but when i am trying to run my project its giving same error again and again.

```
13:24:12 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-03-28 13:24:12 - PrintOutApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Play Have SDK link : http://help.analytics.upsight.com/api-sdk-reference/downloads/

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?  If so, do both projects export the support library?  Only one should.  (By export, I mean is it checked when you go into the project properties->java build path)

Comment: @Gabe - I have tried this, but its not working.

Comment: The problem is only with PlayHaven SDk. PLease import and check.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. remove android-support-v4.jar from your project [not from Haven SDK project
2. remove android-support-v4.jar from you project and copy it from haven sdk project

Comment: Please import this SDK once and check. I have tried every possible thing but didn't succeeded yet :(

Comment: I've imported and didn't find any issues. Can you show me libs of your project?

Comment: Have you run your project?

Comment: it contains only android-support-v4.jar

Answer (score 0):

Check your project for multiple of the same file.
Use a simple file search to look for *.jar in your project files.
Some files may be named differently (I wish SDK makers would not do this) and contain the exact same libraries.

I ran into this issue myself, and it was exactly this file android-support-v4.jar. However, one of the SDK's I used renamed that file to something else. So it was a hard find.